# TypeError: browser.elementSubmit is not a function

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I'm new to Webdriver.io
I find this code on webdriver.io
`browser.elementSubmit(elementId)`

But when I tried, I got this error:

```
[0-0] TypeError in "API Command Login Form"
TypeError: browser.elementSubmit is not a function
    at Context.<anonymous> (E:\Automate with JS\Practice\Phan_2\test_scripts\LoginForm.js:20:13) 
    at Context.executeSync (E:\Automate with JS\Practice\Phan_2\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:38:22)
    at E:\Automate with JS\Practice\Phan_2\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:69:68
```

Here is my code:

```
describe("API Command", () => {
  // 1. Open Page
  it("Login Form", () => {
    browser.navigateTo("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login");

    // 2. Cho username, password, login button visible
    const uName = $("#username");
    uName.waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 10000 });
    uName.setValue("tomsmith");

    const pWord = $("#password");
    pWord.waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 10000 });
    pWord.setValue("SuperSecretPassword!");

    // const lBtn = $('[type="submit"]');
    // lBtn.waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 3000 });
    // lBtn.click();

    const lForm = '#login'
    browser.elementSubmit(lForm)
    
  });
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: see https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/6044 So use the commented out code

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the explanation!